# UnboundLocalError in Python, despite declaring variable globally

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use a global variable inside a function, and despite declaring the variable globally, and initializing its value, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
  main()
 File "test.py", line 8, in main
  func_check()
 File "test.py", line 5, in func_check
  value += 45
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'value' referenced before assignment
```

Following is the code snippet:

```
value = 0
def func_check():
    value += 45

def main():
    func_check()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify `func_check`

```
def func_check():
    global value
    value += 45
```

Comment: `global` is highly discouraged. It is better to use arguments